# PHP Warning: Phar::mapPhar(): open_basedir restriction in effect - Drush

Tags: linux, drupal, cpanel, drush, open-basedir

I install Drush on my cloudlinux and cagefs shared Hosting server.I am admin of server. I use this article for install drush on my server: How to install Drush in cPanel with CloudLinux and CageFS

Commands that I running:

```
    cd
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.drush.org/drush.phar
chmod +x drush.phar
mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush

nano /etc/cagefs/conf.d/drush.cfg
```

And add this content:

```
[drush]
comment=Allow drush to work on the server
paths=/usr/local/bin/drush
```

then run:

```
cagefsctl --force-update
```

I give shell access to an existing user on my cpanel and login with user to ssh . So I am here: **/home/cpaneluser** after run any drush command such as drush help give me this error lines:

> PHP Warning: Phar::mapPhar(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/usr/local/bin/drush) is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp) in /usr/local/bin/drush
>   on line 9 PHP Warning: require(phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/drush):
>   failed to open stream: phar error: no directory in
>   "phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/drush", must have at least
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/drush/ for root directory (always use full
>   path to a new phar) in /usr/local/bin/drush on line 10 PHP Fatal
>   error: require(): Failed opening required
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/drush'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') in
>   /usr/local/bin/drush on line 10

Please help me.What is reasone of these errors?

I disable openbasedir in whm and update cagefs but this error exist.How can I desable openbasedir for a user in cagefs cloudlinux server?